# Strict Base64 encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, base64

I'm working on a project that uses the following Base64 methods for decoding (edit: these are methods from the Ruby Base64 library, I'm just showing their implementation here for clarity):

```
def urlsafe_decode64(str)
  str = str.tr("-_", "+/")
  if !str.end_with?("=") && str.length % 4 != 0
    str = str.ljust((str.length + 3) & ~3, "=")
  end
  strict_decode64(str)
end

def strict_decode64(str)
  str.unpack1("m0")
end
```

unpack1 (haven't found `pack_unpack_internal` yet):

```
static VALUE
pack_unpack1(VALUE str, VALUE fmt)
{
    return pack_unpack_internal(str, fmt, UNPACK_1);
}
```

I am trying to write a Regular Expression that validates incoming Base64-encoded strings to avoid the "invalid base64" error. Here's the RegExp (length of multiple of four, alphanumeric/+/- only, with 0-2 padding = characters at the end):

```
/^(?:([A-Za-z0-9+\/]){4})*(?:([A-Za-z0-9+\/]){2}==|([A-Za-z0-9+\/]){3}=|([A-Za-z0-9+\/]){4})$/
```

My own tests verify that this Regular Expression check is working as I would expect. However, some strings that get past this check are still creating errors in the decoding.

For example, "cg==" is decoded without problem, but "cd==" returns an "invalid base64" error.

It appears that only certain combinations of letters are actually valid Base64, but I haven't been able to find anything online verifying this.

Does anyone have a RegExp that would work with this strict encoding?

Comment: Is there a reason for rolling your own URL-safe encode/decode rather than using the ``Base64`` module from the Ruby standard library?

Comment: *only certain combinations of letters are actually valid Base64* - never heard about that

Comment: mlockerd, those methods are from the Base64 module from the Ruby standard library. I just showed their implementation here in case it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, a more senior colleague of mine said that attempting to validate Base64 via RegExp is really not a good idea since it's all about bits/size...and that the only real way to validate if something is a proper Base64 encoded string is to decode it. :-}